# Ramp(sin(t)) whats the graph of this function?

Tags: math, function

If T = 1 and ramp(t/T), when you substitute t for sin(t), the interval 0<t<=1 is now sin(0)< sin(t)<=sin(1) or is it 0< sin(t)<= 1?.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time the sin(x) function goes into negative territory, the ramp(x) function will multiply it by zero.

[image]

**EDIT** Other variants

[image]

Comment: But how does it get from those two graphs at the left into the one in the right. Speciially if I want Ramp to not be a line to infinity but a line that cuts at t=1 (or other number) that it looks like a triangle.

Comment: If sin(x) is negative say -0.5, then what will ramp(-0.5) be? ramp(-0.5) will be zero as shown in the graph in the middle. On the right side of ramp(x) every value is mapped on to itself, since the slope is 1. If you want a triangular wave, then you cannot call it a ramp.

Comment: Wikipedia page for the [ramp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramp_function) function